# Why aren't my SharedPreferences loading right after application launch?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to store user input so that when application is closed and then re-launched the user input stays there and not auto deletes itself. But, when I re-launch the application after closing it the user input doesn't appear on screen until the user adds another input. After the user adds another input, the inputs that were added in the session before closing the application now appear on screen. Any idea why this might be happening? Thanks!

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsO2y.jpg) is what's happening in case a visual example is needed.

This is the method that's in charge of loading what the user inputed and I call this method on the `onCreate` method:

```
    public void loadSemesters() {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("SEMESTER_LIST", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Semester>>() {
        }.getType();
        mySemesters = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        if (mySemesters == null) {
            mySemesters = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

This method is in charge of saving the user input:

```
   public void saveSemesters() {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Semester>>() {
        }.getType();
        String json = gson.toJson(mySemesters, type);
        editor.putString("SEMESTER_LIST", json);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: did you check if the your list is not empty or null after launching the app again ?

Comment: I suppose it's not empty because after adding a new Semester the other Semesters that were added now appear on the ListView. Either way, how would I be able to check that? @takieddine

Comment: i suppose your list is semesters so loop the list and log the data in there

Comment: Yes, ```mySemesters``` is an ```ArrayList<Semester>``` @takieddine

Comment: so make a loop for your arraylist and then check as soon as the app starts , check if there is data in there

Comment: It's not empty. The correct size is shown after the ```loadSemesters()``` method is called in ```onCreate``` @takieddine

Comment: try to call it in onstart()

Comment: did you set the values to your views ?

Comment: Still the same issue @takieddine

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: did you check my answer below if that worked for you /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution i guess you forgot to set the data to your views ( Update UI ) after the app restarts so you need to update your UI

```
public void loadSemesters() {
       sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       String json = sharedPreferences.getString("SEMESTER_LIST", null);
       Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Semester>>() {
       }.getType();
       mySemesters = gson.fromJson(json, type);

       //Your have your semeters arraylist , now get the data from the list and 
       //set it to 
      // your views

       if (mySemesters == null) {
           mySemesters = new ArrayList<>();
       }
   }
```

Comment: I don't know how to add the data into the view

Comment: are you using recyclerview with adapter ? when you add the semeters from your edittext ,where do you show them ?

Comment: I'm using ```ListView``` with ```ArrayAdapter<Semester>```

Comment: So call your adapter again , adapter adapter = new adapter( here pass your list).. then set the the adapter to your listview